# Unable to click an input tag with Selenium Chrome driver

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm running with the following packages:

"Selenium.Support" version="3.3.0" targetFramework="net40"

"Selenium.WebDriver" version="3.3.0" targetFramework="net40"

"Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver" version="2.28.0" targetFramework="net40"

"WebDriver.ChromeDriver" version="26.14.313457.1" targetFramework="net40"

And in my test program I'm trying to log into morningstar.com but the clicking never works to submit the username/password.  Any suggestions?  I've seen may people online having issues trying to click.  I've also tried IE and firefox and both didn't work for me.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

    class Class1
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.morningstar.com/members/login.html");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("uim-uEmail-input")).SendKeys("email");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("uim-uPassword-input")).SendKeys("password");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            driver.FindElement(By.Id("uim-login-submit")).Click();
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
        }
    }
}
```

I've also tried using an Action, and the Javascript workaround like other answers online have suggested:

```
        ((IJavaScriptExecutor)(driver)).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.FindElement(By.Id("uim-login-submit")));
```

Any ideas, or is this a bug in selenium?

Comment: Please tell us whats the error that is coming

Answer (score 0):

Click probably works fine, problem could be that your password field is not properly set because value will be stored after `onFocus` event is triggered and you are clicking on submit directly after you write text in your password field.

To test this, try to perform `click()` on username field after you set password. Something like this, I added two clicks:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("uim-uEmail-input")).SendKeys("email");
driver.FindElement(By.Id("uim-uPassword-input")).Click();
driver.FindElement(By.Id("uim-uPassword-input")).SendKeys("password");
driver.FindElement(By.Id("uim-uEmail-input")).Click();
```